# git object graph: how does a commit have more than 1 child?

Tags: git

I don't understand how there could be many commits with the same parent. Does this mean commits could happen simultaneously? That seems unlikely. If commits can't happen simultaneously, then why doesn't git force the user to first merge with the previous commit and then push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create 1000 branches from the same commit and then have some commits in each branch, that commit would have 1000 children, even though those 1000 commits did not happen simultaneously.

Comment: Is branching the only way divergence could occur?

Comment: No, If you are developing in a repository model in which you have the ability to git push
your changes into the origin repository, then you might attempt to push your changes
at any time. This could create problems if some other developer has previously pushed
commits.

Comment: In  that case, why doesn't git force you to merge with the other developer's commit before pushing your commit?

Comment: Maybe, because `that case` is not `the case`. You can `push` anytime you want, then if it was as simple as a fast forward, it would merge automatically. Otherwise, if your current version is different from the version resides in the upstream repo, it forces you to merge before push